# prove that $S^2 \times S^2$ is not homotopy equivalent to the wedge $S^2 \vee S^2 \vee S^4$

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to answer questions on an old prelim. exam. This one has me stumped. I know their fundamental groups are trivial and their homology groups are isomorphic. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The cohomology ring of $S^2\times S^2$ has a nontrivial product, but the ring for the wedge is trivial.

Comment: Thank you! That is very clear :)